# PHP Form Only Submitting Emails From Gmail and No Other Addresses

Tags: php, html

I have an html from. When the user submits the form, I'm sending an email to the given email address using php. Emails to gmail accounts go through perfectly fine. However, mails to providers like yahoo, aol etc does not go through.There is no filter mechanism in my code to filter out email addresses. Some mails to yahoo mail addresses goes through rarely. But aol doesn't go at all. What is the issue here?

My html code:

```
<section class="contact-container">
            <div class="container mtb">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 wow fadeInLeft">
                        <h4>Get in touch</h4>
                        <hr>
                            <p>Leave a comment, review, or general musings.
    </p><br/>

    <form method="post" id="captcha_form" name=
    "captcha_form" action="mailform.php"><fieldset><ol>


    </li><li><label class="solo" for="email">Email address:</label>
    <span class="required">(required)</span><input type="text" class="solo 
    input" name="email" id="email" value="" />

    </li><li><label class="solo" for="name">Name:</label><input type=
    "text" class="solo input" name="name" id="name" value="" />



    </li><li><label class="solo" for="subject">Subject:</label>
    <span class="required">(required)</span> <input type="text" class=
    "solo input" name="subject" id="subject" />

    </li><li><label class="solo" for="message">Message:</label>
    <span class="required">(required)</span>
    <div class="solo input"><textarea class="solo input" name="message" id=
    "message" ></textarea><br />

    <p><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" style=
    "float:  right;" /></p></div>
    </li></ol>
    </fieldset></form> &nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;

</div>
```

And here is snippets of mailform.php:

```
 <?php 
    $dontsendemail = 0;
    $possiblespam = FALSE;
    $strlenmessage = "";
    $email = $_REQUEST['email']; 
    $message = $_REQUEST['message']; 
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject']; 
    $emailaddress = "email@gmail.com";

    / Check human test input box
    if(isset($_REQUEST["htest"]) && $_REQUEST["htest"] != "") die
    ("Possible spam     detected. Please hit your browser back button 
    and check your entries."); 
    // Check email address function
    function checkemail($field) {
    // checks proper syntax
    if( !preg_match( "/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+
    ([a-zA-Z0-  9._-]+)+$/", $field))
    {
        die("Improper email address detected. Please hit your browser back 
    button and enter a proper email address."); 
        return 1;
    }
    }

    // Spamcheck function
    function spamcheck($field) {
    if(preg_match("/to:/i",$field) || preg_match("/cc:/i",$field) 
    ||   preg_match("/\r/i",$field) || preg_match("/i\n/i",$field) 
    ||    preg_match("/%0A/i",$field)){ 
        $possiblespam = TRUE;
    }else $possiblespam = FALSE;
    if ($possiblespam) {
        die("Possible spam attempt detected. If this is not the case, please 
    editthe content of the contact form and try again.");
        return 1;
    }
    }

    if ($dontsendemail == 0) {
    $message="";
    $message.="Name: ".$name."\r\n";
    $message.="Mailing Address: \r\nLine 1: ".$addressline1."\r\nLine 
    2: ".$addressline2."\r\nCity: ".$city."\r\nState: ".$state."
    \r\nZip:  ".$zip."\r\n";
    $message=$message."\r\nMessage:\r\n".$_REQUEST['message'];
    mail($emailaddress,"$subject",$message,"From: $email" ); 
    include "email_sent.php";
    echo "Thank you, I will respond shortly.";
}
```

Comment: As regards email address validation, see Charles’s comment below. Further, if you test the email and subject fields for a line break character (`/[\r\n]/`), you should be able to dodge header injection which requires starting on a new line. Validating an email address properly will also avoid header injection, since line breaks and commas are disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex to confirm email addresses. The real regex is like a day long. Use http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp or https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/ or https://github.com/appskitchen/emailverifier/blob/master/class.emailverify.php . You'll notice they are much more complicated than a basic regex. The email spec is insane: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822

Comment: More specifically, `if(!filter_var($field,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) die(…);`. See (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). Requires 5.2, but you should be using at least that.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. :)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. I am fairly new to php, and copied and pasted a lot of my code. I will have to ask you for more specification as to what I am to take from these sites. Thank you in advanced for your understanding.